# Не проходит один из тестов.Нужна оптимизация скорости выполнения кода на Си

Tags: c, оптимизация

Задача: Дан массив. Размер не превышает 10000 элементов. Его вводят через стандартный поток ввода. Сначала вводят длину массива (N) - натуральное число. Затем следует N целых чисел (не выходят за диапазоны int) - элементы массива. Найдите и распечатайте в стандартный поток вывода единственное число:

Количество элементов массива, каждый из которых встречается в массиве не более 3-х раз.

Напишите программу на языке Си.

Последний тест выполняется долго и тест выводит "тайм-аут".

```
int main() {
    int n, arr[10000] = {0};

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    int max = -1, min = 10000;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }

    int result = 0;

    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        int rep = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(arr[j] == i) {
                rep++;
            }
        }
        if(rep > 0 && rep <= 3) {
            result++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Прикрепляю входные данные. Заранее спасибо.
[Входные данные](https://transfiles.ru/n094y)

Comment: Сначала массив надо отсортировать (см. man [qsort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) (или другой сортировкой, работающей за `N * Log(N)`)), а потом один раз пройтись по нему, подсчитывая количество повторов каждого числа (понятно, что одинаковые числа после сортировки будут рядом)

Comment: В последнем цикле у вас странная логика! Вы в цикле берете min, ищите с ним сходство, потом в цикле происходит min+1 и вы ищите сходство с этим числом. Т.е. вы ищите к примеру 10000 в массиве, а в следующем цикле происходит 10000+1 (i++) и вы начинаете искать 10001 ;)

Comment: Можно заморочиться и реализовать хеш-таблицу число -> сколько раз встречалось, и уточнять ответ сразу при чтении каждого числа: если числа еще нет в таблице, то увеличивать ответ на 1, иначе если число уже встречалось три раза, то уменьшать ответ на 1. Таким образом, окончательный ответ будет известен сразу после завершения чтения элементов массива, и итоговая сложность выйдет близкая к O(N).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас подход странный — идти не от массива, а от значений. Если в данные внести какие-нибудь 1000000000 и -1000000000, то получается страшное...

Вот, даже если не стремиться к O(N log N), а ограничиться O(N^2)...

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int c;
} arr[10000];

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &arr[i].a);

    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].c) continue;

        arr[i].c = 1;
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            if(arr[j].a == arr[i].a) arr[j].c = ++arr[i].c;
        if (arr[i].c >= 1 && arr[i].c <= 3) result++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Этого при ваших 10000 элементов вполне должно хватать (ваш удвоенный (до 10000 элементов) массив ваша программа на моей машине берет за 180 мс, моя за 30 мс, но главное, что моя не зависит от значений в массиве.

Главное — надо не перебирать (в пределе) весь диапазон `int` в 4 с лишним миллиарда, а идти от массива.

O(N log N) можно получить, отсортировав за O(N log N), а потом проходя по массиву и проверяя количество одинаковых подряд.

```
int cmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return *(int*)a < *(int*)b ? -1 : *(int*)a > *(int*)b
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10000] = {0};
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    qsort(arr,n,sizeof(int),cmp);

    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int cnt = 1;
        if (i < n-1 && arr[i] == arr[i+1])
        {
            int a = arr[i++];
            while(i < n && arr[i] == a)
            {
                ++i;
                ++cnt;
            }
            if (i < n) --i;
        }
        if (cnt <= 3) result++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Эта у меня работает порядка 10 мс, но даже приведенная первой программа справляется быстро — очень уж небольшое у вас количество данных.

Comment: Ну теперь он скопипастит и всё! ;) А понять где накосячил и почему :) Но с другой стороны SO стал местом задавания вопросов, по решению заданий преподов :) И такие "хацкеры" сдают экзамены, получают дипломы программистов ;) Их нужно в бухгалтеры! Ибо начисление зарплаты с прибавлением значения цикла прикольная фишка =)))

Comment: `Затем следует N целых чисел (не выходят за диапазоны int)` ... `return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;` В данном конкретном случае не лучший выбор для компаратора, т.к. возможно знаковое целочисленное переполнение. [Пример](https://godbolt.org/z/xrq9jWrKa).

Comment: @wololo Согласен. Но должен же я был где-то нахомутать? :) Ладно, сейчас перепишу.